# Area of overlap between two images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two binary images (ground truth and test image).  Each one has objects as black pixels and all other area as white pixels. I want to check if my algorithm's output image complies with the ground truth image. For that, I want to find area of overlap in these two.

How can I find the area of overlap in two images?

Comment: Curious if [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25546552/3293881) posted here worked for you?

Comment: Yaa.. Thanks buddy.. This worked well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `BW1` and `BW2` to be the two binary images, you can calculate the "overlapping area" in pixels with this -

```
ovlp_area = nnz(BW1 & BW2);
```

1. `&` gets us the binary image with white pixels for the overlapping area.
2. `nnz` counts the number of true values, which is the count of pixels in the overlapping region.

You can do the same with `sum`:

`ovlp_area = sum(sum(a1 & a2))`

or

`ovlp_area = sum(reshape((a1 & a2),[],1))`

But I doubt if these will be more efficient in terms of runtime when compared against the `nnz` approach.